Why does using a destructor for my class definition lead instantly to an error?
I am learning about some C++ and I am encountering difficulties with destructor.
I have this easy piece of code :
class A {
    int member;
    ~A();
};


void some_function() {
    A a; // Line 1
    A b = a; // Line 2
    b = a; // Line 3
}

The error is:

error: variable of type 'A' has private destructor

I'd like to know at which line in the function this code fails
I know that a destructor is by default private so a user doesn't have access to it, but why does such a simple line generate an error?
I think it fails at line 2 because this line requires a copy constructor to create b but a was already destroyed due to the class definition, but I'd like to have an detailed answer on why.

The compilation fails on line 1 also.  Why do you believe the compiler should wait until line 3 (or further) for the compiler to figure out that A has an unavailable destructor?  The a object has to be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope anyway.

Your error message explicitly tells you which two lines invoke the error.   You don't need to  guess or ask others.

It fails at both line 1 and line 2, both for the same reason although (quality of implementation) a particular compiler may only give an error for one of them.
In your code, As destructor is private, so only friends or members of A can access/call it.
a and b both have automatic storage duration, within the function block of some_function(), so cease to exist when the scope ends (i.e. the function returns).
Destroying an object (instance of a class) requires calling its destructor, so  requires the destructor to be accessible to some_function().  But some_function() is neither a member nor a friend of A, so does not have required access.

The default destructor is not private.
In your class A, as you never write public:, the default visibility is private and so you declare your new destructor as private.
The compiler stops at line 1 of some_function because it realises it will never be able to destruct this object automatically.

If you didn't include any declaration of it, the compiler would implicitly generate a public destructor--it's private in your case because you declared it to be private.
Both a and b are local to main, so when execution flows off the end of main, both need to be destroyed. That's what triggers the problem with the destructor being private.

Your first sentence is all wrong. The question is about the destructor not the constructor. Class members are private by default, not public. The destructor is not private because the OP declared it that way, but because they didn't declare it as public.

@RemyLebeau: thanks for pointing out the typo. But the rest of what you've said is nonsense (and I'm pretty sure you know it). If you define a class without declaring any members: class foo{};, by default it'll have a public ctor and dtor, so you can create and destroy instances of it. https://godbolt.org/z/febMdz6fr They only become private if you explicitly declare them to be private.

An implicitly generated constructor/destructor is always public, yes. But an explicitly declared constructor/destructor uses whatever visibility the user specifies for it, and in this example that is private since no visibility is being specified explicitly and private is the default for all explicitly declared members. So the 1st sentence in your answer is at best misleading because the code in question is using an explicitly declared destructor, which is NOT public by default and requires an explicit public applied to it.

@RemyLebeau: I don't think it's misleading to say "it's private in your case because you declared it to be private", but I've reworded to be more explicit anyway.

I find "because you declared it to be private" to be misleading. The OP did not declare it private. They simply did not declare it public. There's a difference, even though the end result is the same.

@RemyLebeau: Yes, they did declare it private. If you remove the declaration it would be public. And you know this full well. Yes, I realize what you're getting at, but you're just plain wrong.

class A { int member; ~A(); }; it is implicitly private, not declared private. But whatever. We're going around in circles. I'll stop.
